# How to make Flex Grid width relative to the biggest child's width?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have something like this :

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
}

.content {
  flex: auto;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.col {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='content'>Content</div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col'>aa</div>
    <div class='col'>aaaa</div>
    <div class='col'>aaaaaa</div>
    <div class='col'>aaaaaaaa</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can't understand how :

- The width of the `.row` element is calculated
- The width of the `.col` elements are calculated
- Why some content overflows the box and some don't

What I want is a grid system that gets its size relative to the largest child, so that each content fits in its `.col` cell.

I saw that I could do that with `display: grid` and `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr`, but then how do you make it responsive and how well is it supported ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your 3 first questions, you simly need to remove the `width:25%` to have the following:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
}

.content {
  flex: auto;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.col {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='content'>Content</div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col'>aa</div>
    <div class='col'>aaaa</div>
    <div class='col'>aaaaaa</div>
    <div class='col'>aaaaaaaa</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

We didn't define any width, so each `col` will fit its content and the row will have the width equal to the sum of all the `col`.

Now since we have the width of the row defined based on the content, it won't change and it will get used as a reference for the percentage. Using `25%` for the col means that each one will get `25%` of the previously defined width and we will logically have some overflow since the content inside each `col` isn't the same.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
}

.content {
  flex: auto;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.col {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.width .col {
  width:25%;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='content'>before width</div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col'>aa</div>
    <div class='col'>aaaa</div>
    <div class='col'>aaaaaa</div>
    <div class='col'>aaaaaaaa</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='content'>after width</div>
  <div class='row width'>
    <div class='col'>aa</div>
    <div class='col'>aaaa</div>
    <div class='col'>aaaaaa</div>
    <div class='col'>aaaaaaaa</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

To obtain what you want, I think the `1fr` of CSS grid is the way to go (like you already noticed). Actually CSS grid is well supported. You will simply have issues with IE and you can follow this link to see the known bugs: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid

---

In order to make it responsive you may consider media query to switch to a column layout on small screens:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
}
.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns:1fr;
  grid-auto-flow:column;
}

.col {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media all and (max-width:500px) {
.row {
  grid-auto-flow:row;
}
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='content'>Content</div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col'>aa</div>
    <div class='col'>aaaa</div>
    <div class='col'>aaaaaa</div>
    <div class='col'>aaaaaaaa</div>
  </div>
</div>
```